# Laravel Livewire Bind Data array in Modal

Tags: php, laravel, data-binding, modal-dialog, laravel-livewire

I have "questions" and "choices" table. And I have dynamic fields for "choices" table and stored it perfectly in the database. My problem is the edit/update method when I fetch does stored data from the database going to blade it will show.

I want to show data in the blade file using array. Should I need to put it in the mount() if so how to do it? Please see below code.

**This is my Livewire Component**

```
class ViewPromo extends Component
{
public $inputs = [0];
public $choices = [];
public $questions;
public $question_title = '';
public $question_type;

    public function addRowForChoice() {
        $this->inputs[] = 1;
    }
    
    public function deleteRowForChoice($key) {
        unset($this->inputs[$key]);
    }
    
    public function storeQuestion() {
        $this->validate();
        $question = Question::create([
            'title' => $this->question_title,
            'type' => $this->question_type
        ]);
    
        $question->promo()->attach($this->promo_id);
    
        foreach($this->choices as $key => $choice) {
            $choiceID = Choice::create([
                'choice' => $this->choices[$key],
            ]);
            $question->choices()->attach($choiceID);
        }
    }
    
    public function editQuestion($id) {
        $question = Question::with('choices')->findOrFail($id);
    
        $this->inputs = [0];
    
        $this->choices = [];
    
        foreach($question->choices as $key => $value) {
            $this->inputs[$key] = $value;
            $this->choices[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    
    public function mount($id) {
        $getPromo = Promo::with('questions')->find($id);
        $this->questions =  $getPromo->questions()->get();
    }
    
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.admin.promos.view-promo')->extends('layouts.app')->section('contents');
    }

}
```

**This is my Blade File**

```
<div wire:ignore.self id="edit-default-modal">
    <form wire:submit.prevent='updateQuestion'>
        @foreach ($inputs as $key => $value)
            <div wire:key="{{ $key }}" class="mb-2">
                <div class="flex">
                    <x-input-text wire:model="choices.{{ $key }}"></x-input-text>
                    <x-button wire:click.prevent="deleteRowForChoice({{ $key }})">delete</x-button>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
        
        <div>
            <x-button wire:click.prevent="addRowForChoice()">Add</x-button>
            <x-button wire:target="updateQuestion">Save</x-button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```